# Why the block time is 6s here?

Tags: block-time

https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/pull/2213/files#diff-04c884d6f18e6732821418360f30ce293a09a5a817672f3a5d100d82696f70d1R721

```rs
let info_provider = timestamp_with_aura_info(6000);
```

IIRC, the block time of all cumulus nodes is 12s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an oversight. You are right and it should be `12000`.